# Calculation of a Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I have to calculate the following integral:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1} \bigg((1-x)^{-\alpha} - (1+x)^{-\alpha}\bigg)x^{-\beta}\,dx $$

I know that this integral converges when $\beta <2, \alpha < 1, \alpha + \beta >0.$

My attempt
\begin{align}
I &=  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1-x}^{1+x} \alpha z^{-\alpha -1} x^{-\beta}\,dz\,dx\\ 
&= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y}\alpha(1+z)^{-1-\alpha}x^{-\beta}\,dz\,dx - \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\alpha(1-z)^{-1-\alpha}x^{-\beta}\,dz\,dy\\ 
&= \alpha \int_{0}^{1}\int_{z}^{1}x^{-\beta}\big((1+z)^{-1-\alpha} - (1-z)^{-1-\alpha}\big)\,dx\,dz\\ &= \frac{\alpha}{\beta - 1} \int_{0}^{1} z^{1-\beta}\big((1+z)^{-1-\alpha} - (1-z)^{-1-\alpha} \big)\, dx\,dz
\end{align}

Another approach: I can write $(1+z)^{-1-\alpha} - (1-z)^{-1-\alpha}$ as an series. Then I get
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{\alpha}{\beta - 1} \int_{0}^{1} z^{1-\beta}\big((1+z)^{-1-\alpha} - (1-z)^{-1-\alpha} \big)\, dx\,dz\\ &= \frac{\alpha}{\beta - 1} \int_{0}^{1} z^{1-\beta} 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {-1-\alpha\choose 2n-1} z^{2n-1}\, dz \\ &= \frac{2\alpha}{\beta - 1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {-1-\alpha\choose 2n-1}(2n -\beta +1)^{-1}
\end{align}

Unfortunately in both cases, I don't know what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to separate the two terms ? This looks like beta and gamma functions (I think).

Comment: For $\beta<1$ the integral $\int_0^1(1+x)^{-\alpha}x^{-\beta}\,dx=(1-\beta){}_2F_1(\alpha,1-\beta;2-\beta;-1)$ [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Kummer's_theorem_(z_=_%E2%88%921)) a closed form (in terms of the $\Gamma$ function) if $\beta+\alpha/2$ is an integer. Otherwise you have only the above hypergeometric expression (or its "incomplete beta function" version if you prefer).